# Creating a function from IntPtr

Tags: c#, .net

I have an IntPtr which points to a memory address which is the start of a function without arguments (it is callable).
Specially I am trying to convert this C code into C#:

```
LPVOID executable_area = VirtualAlloc(NULL, len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

memcpy(executable_area, box, len);
VirtualProtect(executable_area, len, PAGE_EXECUTE, &old_protect);

int(*f)() = (int(*)()) executable_area;
f();
```

This is what I got so far:

```
IntPtr executable_area = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, Class2.len, 0x00001000 | 0x00002000, 0x04);
Marshal.Copy(Class2.c, 0, executable_area, Class2.c.Length);
uint old_protect = 0;
bool result = VirtualProtect(executable_area, Class2.len, 0x10, out old_protect);
```

This code works. Now comes the trickier part: Calling the memory.
I tried creating a Func object with Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer, but this does not work with Func

Is there anyway to create a function out of an address, which is stored in an IntPtr?

Comment: What is the calling convention of your native function?

Comment: There is a statement in the docs saying "Generics are not supported in interop scenario". If that's the issue, just define your own delegate type which returns whatever type you need

Comment: Also for that C, I'd expect it to be delcared as accepting `void`, and for style have a space after the return type, i.e. `int (*f)(void)`

Comment: @canton7 yes that is the problem. Is there a post how to create my own delegate?

Comment: E.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-declare-instantiate-and-use-a-delegate). Just `public int MyDelegate();` to declare the delegate type `MyDelegate` which accepts nothing and returns an `int`

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? To execute some arbitrary code that resides in a data-segment?

Comment: yes. And I think the problem has something to do with x64 bit. The arbitrary code is x64 as well as the C# code.